# Appending a link to a li element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append an `a` link to the list items but I am struggling figuring out how to get the `a` link with the textnode.

So basically I want something along the lines of

```
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumble">Bumble</a></li>
```

I have managed to get the li's outputting correctly, I just don't understand how I have the a element as part of the output too.

Here is all the code

```
//Process the JSON data
    function processResponse (){
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                console.log(response[1])
                //Grab suggestions div from DOM
                var suggestions = document.getElementById('suggestions');
                //Create new element UL
                var list = document.createElement('UL');
                //Create new elements for li's
                var newLi, newText ;
                //For all the text nodes
                var textNodes = [];
                //For all the li's
                var liList = [];
                //For all the links
                var links = [];
                //For loop to add and append all suggestions 
                for (var i = 0; i < response[1].length; i++) {

                    links[i] = document.createElement('a');
                    var setHTML = response[1][i].replace(/\s/g, '_');
                    var link = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+setHTML;

                    links[i].href = link;
                    //Create new text node with the response from api
                    textNodes[i] = document.createTextNode(response[1][i]);
                    //Create a new element 'li' into array
                    liList[i] = document.createElement('li')
                    //Append the response(textnode) to the li in the array
                    liList[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]); 
                    //Append the li to the UL 
                    list.appendChild(liList[i]);
                }
                console.log(links);
                //Append the UL to the suggestions DIV
                suggestions.appendChild(list);
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request');
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nope, the task is to do it in pure JavaScript! Annoying lol

Comment: add an id to the li you want to append a link then use `document.getElementById('your li id').innerHTML ="what you want to append";` in your script

Comment: Can you post what `httpRequest.responseText` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the `a` elements, but you never put them in the `li` elements. Currently, your code does

```
//Append the response(textnode) to the li in the array
liList[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]);
```

Maybe you wanted

```
//Append the response(textnode) to the a in the array
links[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]);
//Append the a to the li in the array
liList[i].appendChild(links[i]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks! This appendChild is like inception the film! Confusing haha!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < response[1].length; i++) {
    links[i] = document.createElement('a');
    var setHTML = response[1][i].replace(/\s/g, '_');
    var link = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+setHTML;

    links[i].href = link;
    links[i].text = response[1][i];
    //Create new text node with the response from api
    //textNodes[i] = document.createTextNode(response[1][i]);
    //Create a new element 'li' into array
    liList[i] = document.createElement('li')
    //Append the response(textnode) to the li in the array
    liList[i].appendChild(links[i]); 
    //Append the li to the UL 
    list.appendChild(liList[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Append the text node to the link, and append *that* to the `li`:

```
textNodes[i] = document.createTextNode(response[1][i]);
links[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]);

liList[i] = document.createElement('li')
liList[i].appendChild(links[i]); 

list.appendChild(liList[i]);
```